# How to change the tabControl tab pages label font, font color and font size in VB 2012

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I'm  still a beginner in VB.NET and it's been 2 days already that i've been looking for answers to this question in the Net but still unsuccessful.

Comment: Good ole Microsoft, it happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported as a bug and, if I'm reading correctly, MS have confirmed it. [Here's the bug report](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814345) with a programmatic workaround.

Hope this helps :)